# Text needs to span 2 rows, not able to do it using lists, divs or tables

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do this:

[image: pic]

Seems simple enough, but no matter what I try I can't seem to get it working. Here is my fiddle effort with divs: http://jsfiddle.net/RPEpQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `float:left` to `div.one`.

Here you go, http://jsfiddle.net/RPEpQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set `float: left` on the element holding the number 34. See your modified [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Meucz/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to `float: left` your `.one` element, and fit `line-height` so that the `.two` element has half the line height of the `.one` element.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RPEpQ/4/).

Answer (score 0):

```
.outer {
  width: 160px;
}

.one {
  float:left;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height:40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.two {
  width:120px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height:20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RPEpQ/6/
This works for me.

```
<div class = "outer">
  <div class = "one">34</div>
  <div class = "two">times I have eaten here</div>
</div>​

.outer {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline;
}
.one {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}
.two {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 5em;
    height: 3.4em;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    float:left;
    padding-left:0.5em;
}​
```